# A question of style -"Als" in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

> Wir haben auf den Lehrer gewartet als passierte der Unfall.

Does this sound natural?

Comment: You can only have one conjugated verb per clause. That means the part with *als* is a second clause. You need a comma in front of it and it has to follow the word order rule of dependent clauses. *Try again.*

Comment: So how should the sentence look then?

Comment: Dependent clauses have their conjugated verb at the end in German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wir haben auf den Lehrer gewartet, als der Unfall passierte.

That would be the right way of saying it. An alternative would be: Wir haben auf den Lehrer gewartet, während der Unfall passierte.

Comment: *während* implies that they *we* were still waiting while the accident was in the process of going down, ie. it didn't happen to *us*. And it doesn't sound right for other reasons, too. Following [this fine answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50784/35977), it seems the sentence better had say "Als wir auf den Lehrer warteten, passierte der Unfall"; Although I would accept your first variant, and therefore don't quite agree with that answer, it sounds authoritative and may be helpful for good style. Is subordinating the "als" clause trying to parallel English "..., when ..."?

Comment: Umgangssprachlich würde ich beide Aussagen als valide durchgehen lassen. Dein Vorschlag ist natürlich sauberer, nur wollte ich die vorgegebene Satzstellung nicht ändern.

Comment: but only assuming that the accident didn't happen to *us*, which is not at all clear without any context.